# Defining a part of a column as a unique field in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy 0.5 i have a table defined like this one:

```
orders = Table('orders', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('responsable', String(255)),
    Column('customer', String(255)),    
    Column('progressive', Integer),
    Column('date', Date),
    Column('exported', Boolean()),    
)
```

Is it possible to define only the customer and year of the date as unique ?
The year isn't a column only a part of a date but it could be nice to have the year of the date and the customer to be a single key of the table.
Is it possible in sqlalchemy 0.5 ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question confuses UNIQUEness (which is required of primary keys) with indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without splitting the date field into a month field, a date field, and a year field, there really isn't a way to do what you're asking. It would (probably) be easier and simpler for you to include the whole date (month/day/year) in the composite primary; if (id, year) uniquely defines a record, then so will (id, date).

Answer (score 0):

Quoth the [documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/metadata.html):

> Multiple columns may be assigned the
>   primary_key=True flag which denotes a
>   multi-column primary key, known as a
>   composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in a constraint but it's not database independent. See here for details: [Compound UniqueConstraint with a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510018/compound-uniqueconstraint-with-a-function)

However I would argue that the best thing to do would be to create a column for year. It will certainly be easier.